# Wrapping my head around generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am going on with refactoring my code base while migrating from Python 2 to Python 3. I am using generators to make reusable components this time as I am more comfortable with them this time then last time. But there are times when I am stuck at their use. Like below example. These two are essentially same with one infinitely generating and other with a limit.

Is there a way to make these as one function? Normally an extra optional parameter as limit will do the trick but with generators I am not sure how to use them. Is there some way to do that?

```
def fibonacci_inf(a, b):
    """Lazily generates Fibonacci numbers Infinitely"""
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b


def fibonacci(a, b, num):
    """Lazily generates Fibonacci numbers"""
    while b < num:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Comment: I don't use Python much, but why wouldn't an optional argument work here? Pseudocode: `while(!optionalArgumentExists || optionalArgumentCondition)`.

Comment: @Ocelot20 Exactly my point. But I couldn't wrap my head around actual syntax without making this a mess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just implement the infinite generator, and use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to limit it:

```
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x : x < 8, fibonacci_inf(0,1)))
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Having spent some time with Haskell I can really appreciate this now. Another reason why I should go over the standard library again once in a while.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
def sequence(start, end = None):
    loopIndefinitely = end is None   

    curr = start    
    while loopIndefinitely or curr <= end:
        yield curr
        curr += 1

## Prints: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
for i in sequence(1, 10):
    print(i)

## Prints: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
for j in sequence(1):
    if(j > 10):
        break
    else:
        print(j)
```

Used `sequence` instead since the variable names more clearly show the use vs. `a, b, num`.

I think it's important to:

1. Clearly define what argument values lead to what functionality (for example, defining a clearly named variable like `loopIndefinitely` to show immediately what an `end` value of `None` means).
2. Determine when it's appropriate to use an optional argument. This one is a bit tougher, but it may have been clearer to define two functions called `range` and `infiniteSequence`. In this example the code is pretty simple to share or even duplicate, but with a more complex function you may want to have two functions that both point to a third one that has most of the reusable code.

Comment: One variation when the logic is this simple is to check the optional argument once and branch--either to separate functions as you suggest or inline. It's a minor performance improvement but may help to highlight how the optional argument applies.